# Is it possible to change the behaviour of a processor in runtime using mule 4 API?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

Lets say if there are two flows A and B in a mule application.
flow A has some processers and flow B performs some batch processing like loading data from a hadoop datastore and performing data wrangling and saving data to CSV files.

Flow A triggers flow B and also flow A and flow B are decoupled in asynchronous strategy either using a VM or JMS.

my questions

Is it possible using mule API to change the behavior of flow B at runtime? for example, to change dynamically a dataweave script to accommodate some error cases, without stopping the application.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit abstract, however the use case about changing DataWeave dynamically is more specific. You can execute dynamically DataWeave scripts. This is a KB on how to do that for Mule 3: https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Dynamic-DataWeave-Script